# Creating a table from iterating through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, html

I have two types of arrays,

```
var arr1 = ["mike", "john"];
var arr2 = [{ 
    dan: {name: "dan brown", occupation: "police officer", age: 25},
    john: {name: "john blake", occupation: "student", age: 20},
    mike: {name: "mike floss", occupation: "student", age: 19}
    }];
```

I have displayed the tablebody using the following code.

```
function loopArray(arr1, arr2) {
    $.each(arr1, function(i) {
        var templateString = '<table id="partstable" class="table table-hover"><tbody><tr><td class="name">' 
        + arr2[arr1[i]].name + '</td><td>' 
        + arr2[arr1[i]].occupation + '</td><td>'
        + arr2[arr1[i]].age + '</td>';
        $('#test').append(templateString);
    })
}
```

and calling this function.

This is the output I have gotten.

[image: This is the output I have gotten.]

I would like to find out whether there is a way to add headers **name, occupation and age** to the table and whether there is a better way to output a table in general. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use object.keys(arr2[i]) to get the header text of the inner objects - same them out to varaibles or to an array that can be used to give the th header text.

Comment: A better way to construct the table would be to use `Node` elements instead of treating the HTML as plain strings. This allows you to do things like insert nodes into other nodes by appending or prepending.

Comment: I'm still a javascript noob, so idk whether i should advance to learning node and all that :(. I would like to work on some basic javascript stuffs before I move on to learn more advanced libraries.

Comment: @djfdev is referring to [DOM Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), not node.js. I strongly agree with him; if you want to learn JS, drop the reliance on jQuery and get to know the DOM all by yourself.

Comment: Yes, as @BlueWater86 said I was referring to DOM nodes. That being said, you could certainly do the same thing with jQuery selectors ... it’s really just a matter of thinking of the DOM as a tree structure rather than as a large concatenated string.

Comment: https://mobile.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/working_w_tables_using_jquery.html check out this example in jQuery. Also extremely portable to vanilla JavaScript using modern web APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to dynamic table generation (without the need for jQuery) is via the [Table Element API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) which you can use to construct a table dynamically from input data via it's object-orientated interface.

This API provides methods such as [`createTHead()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/createTHead), [`insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) on Table elements, and [`insertCell()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) on row elements which can be used as shown:

```js
var arr1 = ["mike", "john"];
var arr2=[{dan:{name:"dan brown",occupation:"police officer",age:25},john:{name:"john blake",occupation:"student",age:20},mike:{name:"mike floss",occupation:"student",age:19}}];


/* Create table element */
const table = document.createElement('table');

/* Create header element and insert a row */
const header = table.createTHead().insertRow();

/* Populate table header with header cell labels */
header.insertCell(0).innerText = 'Name';
header.insertCell(1).innerText = 'Occupation';
header.insertCell(2).innerText = 'Age';

/* Create body element and insert to table */
const body = document.createElement('tbody');
table.appendChild(body);

arr1.forEach(person => {

  arr2.forEach(item => {

    const data = item[person];

    if (!data) {
      return;
    }

    /* If data present in arr2 for key person then 
    insert row into table body with corresponding 
    data entries */
    const row = body.insertRow();

    row.insertCell(0).innerText = data.name;
    row.insertCell(1).innerText = data.occupation;
    row.insertCell(2).innerText = data.age;
  });
});

/* Append table to test div */
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(table);
```

```css
table thead {
  background:pink;
}

table td {
  padding:0.1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: This answer +1. I honestly had no idea this API even existed until now. Blaming that on my heavy use of React throughout my frontend work haha.